# svn merge with revision not doing what I expect

Tags: svn

I'm trying to do an svn merge of a change from trunk onto a branch (2001).  The change is in trunk on revision 614.

I've tried the following and none of them do what I want :

```
svn merge
svn merge -r 614:HEAD https://secreturl/trunk
```

But this seems to pick up a lot of changes I don't want.

When I ran: `svn log -r 614 https://secreturl/trunk` - I saw the checkin comment for the small subset of changes I wanted to merge.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you merging in a folder which corresponds to a branch of trunk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`svn merge -r 614:HEAD https://secreturl/trunk` will merge **all** changes between revision 614 and HEAD. Moreover, it will take 614 as the base revision (probably not what you want happenning :)

To merge changes from a specific revision, you can use one of two methods:

`$ svn merge -c 614 https://secreturl/trunk` or `$ svn merge -r 613:614 https://secreturl/trunk`.

The first means *apply changes in revision 614 only*, while the second form means *take all changes required to go from r613 to r614 and apply them here*.

Comment: One point that I was missing is that.... svn merge -c OR svn merge -r ... will affect your LOCAL WORKING COPY.  After you do the command line, your local working copy will be the (previous) revision.  Then you can choose to (or choose not to if you don't like what you see) COMMIT the changes to the repository.  I added a comment to my COMMIT that looks liked this : "Manual Change.  Revision 614 was pulled out of repository and then it was made the HEAD Revision." ... That way I know exactly what happened.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want -r 613:HEAD.  If you JUST want change 614, do -r 613:614.

Comment: SVN requires the merge to be specified with the previous number. You will see that when SVN performs that merge that the correct revision umbers will be checkedout in your branch.

Answer (score 2):

`svn log -r 614` will show you the specific 614 revision.  If you want to just merge the results of r614, do this:

svn merge -r 613:614 https://secreturl/trunk

That is, merge the changes from 613 to 614.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I was looking for.  Thanks to the rest of you for answering as well.

Comment: Hmm, this still doesn't seem to be working.  Here's what I tried :

08:55 AM[~/views/2001/platform/L3/src]$svn merge -r 613:614 https://secreturl/trunk

My hope is that the changes will get merged into my 2001 view, which I've cd'ed into.  But the results of the merge are empty.  I would expects some updates given what I see is different in the two branches.

Answer (score 0):

Good site to help you along 
 [Link 1](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html)

Comment: I read that link Phil, and frankly it wasn't clear.  I know, RTFM, but after RTFMing I still didn't get it.

Comment: What version of Subversion are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I took the information above, and made a windows .bat file to show how this can be scripted.
My addition is showing more explicitly how you are dealing with the LOCAL WORKING COPY, and then committing back to the repository.

In the .bat file below, I put in a svn.exe status to show what will happen if you commit, and then a PAUSE, to give you a last chance to X out and not perform the commit.

Here is the .bat file

FYI, I am using svn.exe 1.6.15.

```
 set __SVNClient="C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client\svn.exe"

 set __PreviousRevisionNumber=2594

 set __CheckoutFolder=".\MyCheckoutFolderRevision%__PreviousRevisionNumber%"


 RD %__CheckoutFolder% /Q /S



 %__SVNClient% checkout "https://www.myrepository.com/MyProject/trunk" %__CheckoutFolder% --username %USERNAME%


 CD %__CheckoutFolder%


%__SVNClient% merge --revision HEAD:%__PreviousRevisionNumber% "."



%__SVNClient% status "."



PAUSE



%__SVNClient% commit -m "Manual Change. Revision %__PreviousRevisionNumber% was pulled out of repository and then it was made the HEAD Revision." "." --username %USERNAME%

CD ..



set __CheckoutFolder=
set __PreviousRevisionNumber=
set __SVNClient=
```

This below site (and section name) gives a little more explanation:

http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/version-control-with-subversion-1.6/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html
(Search for "Undoing Changes" as a section header)